# CSRF errors after upgrading to Rails 7, what is causing them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, rails-activestorage

Here is the error

```
An ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken occurred in direct_uploads#create:

  Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
```

We didn't get the error before we upgraded to Rails 7 and only get the error seldomly. 95% of the errors come from the direct_upload controller which makes me think that it has to do something with timing since those requests can take a while when uploading a large file. At one point I wondered if a deploy was occurring during an upload? Do the CSRF tokens change with every deploy or app restart?

Another potential problem could be in the way we upload. Here is our direct upload js code; is that causing an issue?

```
class App.Uploader
  constructor: (file, url) ->
    thisuploader = this
    @file = file
    @url = url
    @directUpload = new ActiveStorage.DirectUpload(file, url, thisuploader)
    @xhrRequest = undefined
    @upload = ->
      @directUpload.create (error, blob) ->
        if error
          console.log error
          $('#uploading_done').text('There was an issue uploading your file.').show().css('background', '#D4524B')
          $('#uploading').hide()
        else
          $('input#podcast_file').val(blob.signed_id).closest('form').submitWithRails()

    @directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR = (request) ->
      that = this
      @xhrRequest = request
      request.upload.addEventListener "progress", (event) ->
        that.directUploadDidProgress(event)

    @directUploadDidProgress = (event) ->
      console.log(3)
      progress = ((event.loaded / event.total) * 100).toFixed(0)
      App.Uploader.updateProgress(progress)

  @updateProgress = (progress) ->
    $('#ul_percent_span').css('width', "#{progress - 1}%")
    $('#ul_percent').text("#{progress - 1}%")

  @startUpload = (file) ->
    input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')
    App.Uploader.inProgress = new App.Uploader(file, input.dataset.directUploadUrl, this)
    App.Uploader.inProgress.upload()
    $("#upload_step1, [data-upload-step='1'], #no_audio, [data-upload-buttons], #upload_btn, #file_error, [data-allowance], #no_file_message").hide()
    $("#upload_step2, #uploading, [data-publish-card]").show()
    $('.waiting_for_file .upload_step_2').css('padding-top', '0')
    ConfirmBeforeNavigatingAway.enable 'Your episode has not finished uploading. Are you sure you want to leave?',  ->
      App.Uploader.inProgress.xhrRequest.abort() if App.Uploader.inProgress.xhrRequest

  @checkUpload = (file) ->
    file_type = file.name.split('.').pop()
    if ['zip', 'pdf', 'aup', 'band', 'jpg', 'png'].includes? file_type
      alert("Your file is not an audio file. You need to upload a file with the extension .wav or .mp3. Don't hesitate to contact support if you need any help!")
    else if file.size > 5000000000
      alert("File size exceeds 5GB limit. Please export your audio to a smaller file size or file type. Don't hesitate to contact support if you need any help!")
    else
      App.Uploader.startUpload file

$(document).on 'click', '[data-behavior="cancel_upload"]', (event) ->
  App.Uploader.inProgress.xhrRequest.abort()

$(document).on 'drop dragenter dragleave dragover', 'body.episodes_new, body.episodes_edit', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()

$(document).on 'dragover', 'body.episodes_new, body.episodes_edit', (event) ->
  if $('[data-behavior="drag_and_drop"]').is(':visible')
    $(@).addClass('drag-over')

$(document).on 'drop dragleave', 'body.episodes_new, body.episodes_edit', (event) ->
  $(@).removeClass('drag-over')

$(document).on 'drop', 'body.episodes_new, body.episodes_edit', (event) ->
  if $('[data-behavior="drag_and_drop"]').is(':visible')
    file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]
    App.Uploader.checkUpload file

# Bind to normal file selection
$(document).on 'change', '#file', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  file = document.getElementById('file').files[0]
  App.Uploader.checkUpload file
```